# Writing a line of text to an open notebook

Tags: notebooks

I realize this is a simple question, but I'm relatively new to Mathematica programming.

I have created a Mathematica Notebook called Index.nb which is open on the desktop in Mathematica

I want to write text strings created in another program to Index.nb

What are the Mathematica functions to use to do this.

If this is any help  Directory[] gives "/Users/lewisrobinson"

Here is an edit of the original question.  It is similar to a question asked previously, but the devil appears to be in the details with files and where they are located, and the file I want to write is in a different place.

0

Thank you LouisB and Syed. The response to both will be rather long, but hopefully is what you want. HyperCard was a great Apple program which I used to take notes on what I read. I accumulated 100+ megaBytes of (mostly) text. The last Apple computer which could run it uses the PowerPC G5. Newer Apples won't run HyperCard as their memory management is different. Nothing lasts forever, and I'm down to my last Apple PowerPC G5 hence the reason for the move.

The HyperCard data is in the form of several types of cards (xref, glossary, index, topics). I wrote programs in HyperCard to move their data and data about them (e.g.metadata) into text files, which are basically a list of strings. These are loaded into the variable iData[] in a Mathematica program which allows me to access each string.

Here is the data and metadata on just two index cards, loaded into a Mathematica noteBook.

In[77]:= iData =
Import [
"/Users/lewisrobinson/Desktop/Hypercard Xref/  IndexCards  100  to  
101", "lines" ]

Out[77]= {"Total Number of Cards =  2 ", "Begin  card "I2582705" ",     
"card id 2582705 ", "5 hydroxylysine ", "No Topic Assigned ", "No 
Topic Identifier ", "3 ", ""Structure " ", "1850661    "glossary" 
", ""Deficiency in type VI Ehlers Danlos syndrome" ", "1048186    
"Xref" ", ""Lysyl hydroxylase" ", "2927558    "Xref" ", "End  
card "I2582705" ", "Begin  card "I5074462" ", "card id 5074462 ",    
"5 methoxy Tryptophan (5MTP) ", "Serotonin ", "t239 ", "1 ", ""An 
endogenous anti-inflammatory agent" ", "2105283    "Xref" ", "End  
card "I5074462" "}
Here is the sort of manipulation I do on iData[]

In[78]:= iData[[1]]

Out[78]= "Total Number of Cards =  2 "

In[90]:= (* Now mimic CardManipulation10.nb *)
numCardsS = StringExtract [ data[[1]], 6]

Out[90]= "2"

In[91]:=
numIndexCardsI = ToExpression [numIndexCardsS]

Out[91]= 2
There is a lot of error checking at each step -- example

If [ IntegerQ  [ numIndexCardsI], Null, showIndexCardVariables [] ]
iDataLN is an integer pointing to a particular string in iData[] Here is one such example of its use

In[106]:= iCardTitle = iData [[iDataLN]]

Out[106]= "5 hydroxylysine "
There is a lot more of this sort of thing as I march through iData[], with many strings given names like iCardTitle etc. etc.

But here is the nub of my question

I went to the File menu of Mathematica and chose new notebook and then saved it as Index.nb and then opened it.

What I want to do is write the string "5 hydroxylysine " to Index.nb

How do I do this? I'm embarrassed to be asking such a simple question, but until I can write strings like this into notebooks of my choice my programming has ground to a halt.

Comment: Have you seen the [RunProcess](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RunProcess.html) command?  It lets us run run external programs and retrieve their output from within a notebook.  The documentation for `RunProcess` command has a few examples and also has the usual "See Also" and "Related Guides" for alternative methods.  Search this forum for more examples of using `RunProcess`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! To make the most of MMA.SE start by taking the **[tour now](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)**. It will help us to help you if you write an **[excellent question](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3)**. In particular, don't make us guess what you have tried. Please **[edit your question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/275321/edit)** to inc
lude a **minimal working example** of the code you are using. Please use **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)** that we can copy-paste and run, instead of a screenshot. I hope you will become a regular contributor.

Comment: Please tell us more about your external program.

Comment: You asked a [similar question](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2383205) on the Wolfram Community site. Have you tried the answers?

Comment: I think this might be what you need: [NotebookWrite](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookWrite.html)